# How do I identify which button was pressed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events

I have seen the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552300/iphone-identify-button-pressed) to this question.

However, I have a page where I add many custom map annotations to a map, and I need to know which AnnotationView's rightCalloutAccessoryView (a UIButton in my case) was pressed.

The ideal would be to set a custom ID attribute on the button. But seeing as I can't find a mechanism to do that, I guess it's not the way.

Comment: If you're using an MKMapView, the calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method is probably the best way to respond to the button press instead of creating your own action method.  The delegate method passes the annotation view as one of it's parameters (and the view also has the annotation itself as one of its properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView` object has a `tag` property you can freely set and read. You may find this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

when you declare your button action method like this: `yourMethod:(id)sender` you will receive a pointer to the button(or whatever object) which called the action, in the sender var

Answer (score -1):

I think some of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview) might help.